# SML: LookSay recursion

Tags: recursion, sml

I am doing self-study on functional programming and there is no teacher could guide me. Thanks for help me!

```
(*lookSay:int list=>int*int list
ENSURE: true
REQUIRE: computes the look-and-say sequence, for example list of l=[2,2,2] which would be read as "three twos"  =>[(2,1),(1,2)] *)
```

here is my code:

```
    fun lookSay(x:int list)=
    case x of
    []=>[]
      | l::ls =>
    let fun helper(l,l'::ls',acc)=
              if l=l'
              then helper(l,ls',acc+1)
              else (acc,l)::lookSay(ls)
    in
        helper(l,ls,1)
    end
```

I don't understant why it doesn't work. the solution offered by others is using a helper function runWith(x,L) returns (repeated, tail) :  but I don't know how to come out this solution..

```
    fun runWith (_:int, [] : int list) : int list * int list = ([], [])
  | runWith (x, y::L) =
    if x = y then
      let
        val (repeats, tail) = runWith(x, L)
      in
        (x::repeats, tail)
      end
    else
      ([], y::L)
```

Comment: Think about how your `helper` handles the case of the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off by formatting your solution like this:

```
fun lookSay [] = []
  | lookSay (x::xs) =
    let
      fun helper(y, z::zs, count) =
          if y = z
          then helper(y, zs, count + 1)
          else (count, y) :: lookSay zs
    in
      helper(x, xs, 1)
    end
```

I've used `x`, `y` and `z` rather than `l` and `l'` because I find that `l` can be hard to read: I can't easily see if it's a lowercase L, an uppercase i, or a 1. Since we're actually using the constant 1 also, this adds to the confusion.

I've also done some variable renaming: You have one pair of `l` and `ls` in the scope of the case-of, and *another identically named* pair of `l` and `ls` inside the helper function that shadow the outer variables. While this works, it is extremely confusing the have different things in close proximity named the same.

Similarly I renamed `acc` into `count` to clarify what it accumulates.

As molbdnilo hinted, your problem lies in a missing pattern match. The ML compiler should warn you of this:

```
! Toplevel input:
! ..........helper(y, z::zs, count) =
!           if y = z
!           then helper(y, zs, count + 1)
!           else (count, y) :: lookSay zs
! Warning: pattern matching is not exhaustive
```

Which hints that `helper` should also have a `[]` pattern.

As for the strategy of this solution: The inner `helper` function does two things that necessitates an inner helper function. First, it has an extra argument for the "current" item, which I called `y`, and second, it has the accumulating argument, which I called `count`. Peculiarly, `helper` calls `lookSay` rather than itself.

But only the second of these is truly necessary, since you can also use the head of the list argument to keep the "current" item:

```
fun lookSay xs =
  let
    fun go [] _ = []
      | go (x::y::zs) count =
        if x = y
        then go (x::zs) (count + 1)
        else (count + 1, x) :: go (y::zs) 0
  in
    go xs 0
  end
```

This strategy looks at the first two elements of a list at once, `x` and `y`, and if they're equal, it discards one but increments `count`. If `x` and `y` are not equal, this marks the end of the sequence of `x`s, so a `(count + 1, x)` element is emitted and `go` can call itself recursively on `y::zs`.

I've preserved the bug that is also present in your example. In my version molbdnilo's hint can be rephrased as "Think about how the `go` function handles lists with exactly one element."

---

I think that to make this function slightly more useful, you want to actually emit a plain list:

```
fun concatMap f xs =
    List.concat (List.map f xs)

fun flatten pairs =
    concatMap (fn (n, x) => [n, x]) pairs

fun lookSay xs =
  let
    fun go [] _ = []
      | go (x::y::zs) i =
        if x = y
        then go (x::zs) (i+1)
        else (i+1,x) :: go (y::zs) 0
  in flatten (go xs 0) end
```

Assuming that the bug gets fixed, this should give you:

```
- lookSay [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3];
> val it = [3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3] : int list
```